# Вопрос о стиле геттеров/сеттеров в C++

Tags: соглашения, ооп, c++

Что предпочитает уважаемое сообщество, и как аргументирует свои предпочтения:

классический вариант:

```
class TFoo
{
    int value;
public:
    int ValueGet() { return value; }
    void ValueSet(int v) { value = v; }
};
```

альтернатива, основанная на перегрузке функций:

```
class TFoo
{
    int value;
public:
    int Value() { return value; }
    void Value(int v) { value = v; }
};
```

интересен взгляд со стороны: что выглядит более логичным и корректным?

Comment: void Value(const int &v);

Comment: Второй вариант ужасен по двум причинам:
1) что делает foo.Value(5) совсем неочевидно для непосвященного читателя кода:
2) перегрузка функций отрицательно сказывается на читаемости кода.

Мне симпатичны названия SetValue и GetValue, они как-то более по-английски звучат :)

Кстати, в objective-c приняты такие стандарты: геттер - value(), сеттер - setValue(). В Qt, если мне не изменяет, так же.

Comment: @y0prst я бы не стал поминать Objective-C, поскольку принятые там стандарты именования методов… ммм… едва ли можно назвать адекватными :).

Answer (score 6):

в C#, C++, Java делаю одинаково:

```
class TFoo
{
    int _Value;
public:
    int getValue() { return _Value; }
    void setValue(int v) { _Value = v; }
};
```

средства генерации кода позволяют такое получить :-)

Comment: в C# и вероятно в Java в этом нет необходимости - там просто есть свойства

Comment: да, в C# прикольно, написал public someobject Value { get; set; }, и радуйся

Answer (score 5):

Зачем нужны эти геттеры и сеттеры? Я конечно не буду предлагать сделать это свойство общедоступным, но можно сделать вот так:

```
#include <iostream>

class TFoo {
    int val;
public:
    int &value() {
        return value;
    }
};
int main() {
    TFoo obj;
    obj.value() = 235;
    std::cout << obj.value();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Дело вкуса.
Первый вариант удобен при чтении кода, второй при написании кода.

Но.

```
class TFoo
{
    int value;
public:
    virtual int Value() { return value; }
    virtual void Value(int v) { value = v; }    
};
```

Код ниже уже не будет работать. Потому что потребуется переопределить второй метод Value(int v), либо using TFoo::Value в теле класса TBoo.

```
сlass TBoo : public TFoo
{
..
    virtual int Value() { /*Делаем нечто специальное*/ }
..

};

...
 TBoo *Boo = new TBoo;
 Boo->Value(5);
...
```

Итог: второй способ возлагает некоторые трудности связаные с перегрузкой функций.

Answer (score 3):

Если это действительно *свойство* - т.е. произвольное количество вызозов не изменяет состояние класса - то `int Value()`, в противном случае - `int GetValue()`. Setter всегда именуется `void SetValue(const ValueType &vt)`, уж больно выглядит как функция.

Comment: "... свойство - т.е. произвольное количество вызозов не изменяет состояние класса ..." - это достигается следующим синтаксисом: int Value() const;

Answer (score 1):

Если уж говорить о свойствах, то разумеется лучше их смоделировать:

```
class TFoo
{
    int value;
public:
    operator int () const { return value; }
    TFoo& operator = (int v) { value = v; return *this; }
};
```

Соответственно, использование такого класса выглядит красиво и без всяких явных вызовов функций.

```
TFoo foo;
foo = 1;
int a = foo;
```

Comment: Оно выглядит красиво, но неочевидно. Плохой стиль. Кроме того, а что будете делать, если добавится ещё свойство?

Comment: Ещё лучше было бы сделать этот класс шаблонным. А так, вообще, оператор приведения к типу обычно преподносит немало неожиданных сюрпризов. Я считаю, что, если в языке нет свойств, но не надо их моделировать. Если бы всё было так просто, наверняка, серьёзные библиотеки вроде упомянутого Qt воспользовались бы ;).

Comment: Один класс - одно свойство, или по другому свойство - это класс :)
Шаблонным - да, если универсально подходить, но если честно, то полной универсальности трудно добиться, все равно придется на каком то этапе остановиться. Например, как будет выглядеть данное свойство если в нем будет указатель на массив целых чисел? Сразу возникает вопрос, а нужно ли оно вам? :)

Comment: Это же упрощённый пример. Если один класс - одно свойство, то не надо заводить класс вовсе.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m возможно именно по этому "свойств" нет в С++. Большинство устраивает работа с методами.

Comment: Смешная шутка заключается в том, что «наличие свойств» — не есть свойство языка. Пример тому Питон. В Питоне, с точки зрения языка, никаких таких свойств нет.

Comment: Ну, вообще в яве тоже нет свойств, если уж так строго подходить к этому вопросу. Они тоже реализуются с помощью методов.

Comment: Я говорил лишь о том, что если в классе только одной свойство, то нет повода вообще заводить этот класс. Но только в этом сомнительном случае вы можете эмулировать свойства в таком стиле, в котором вы предлагаете. Таким образом, выходит, что в нормальных словиях, способ никогда не будет востребован.

Comment: @cy6ergn0m не, мне кажется, тут возникло какое-то недопонимание. Это же не то, что предлагается прямо эти операторы реализовать в рассматриваемом классе. Предлагается этот класс использовать вместо соответствующего типа. И нет никакой проблемы с единственностью свойств, о которой Вы говрите.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m соглашусь с kirelagin. о каком "этом сомнительном случае" тут можно говорить, если нет контекста, не описан "этот случай"? Всего лишь замена одного типа на другой. При приведенных исходных данных мой пример как я уже написал "красивее".

Comment: Он не выглядит красивее. Он не очевиден и "пускает пыль в глаза" первые минуты чтения кода из-за приравнивания непреобразуемых типов (так кажется, пока не откроешь исходник класса).

Comment: @kirelagin  Да, очень возможно..

Comment: @cy6erGn0m ну вот по поводу "приравнивания непреобразуемых типов" которые таковыми только кажутся (сами ведь знаете что нужно делать в таком случае) открывать тут дискуссию уж точно не хотелось бы. Только один маленький контрпример:
A* p = new B;
Правильно это или нет? Ответ: Нужно посмотреть в описание класса "B". Стандарт тоже "пускает пыль в глаза"? ;)

Comment: Господа, дискуссия сейчас скатится к обсуждению вопросов личных предпочтений, поэтому предлагаю новый актуальный вопрос на схожую тему:
http://hashcode.ru/questions/2301/